# "ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432" when using PostgresSQL + Node v12.22.9 + systemd service

Tags: node.js, postgresql, service

I followed these instructions to create an SQL API that interacts via HTTPS with a leaflet map.
[HERE](http://132.72.155.230:3838/js/setting-up-an-sql-api.html)

It worked fine for a month or so but recently I get the ECONNREFUSED error in the server log as the PostgreSQL database seems to be refusing connection.

When I ssh in and run “sudo service postgresql restart” in the terminal the problem stops for a few hours at least. It seems like maybe the service is failing to automatically restart. But in the .serivce file it still says “Restart=always”.

As far a potential causes go I don’t know but several days before the issue began I was made to install Webroot on several macs that connect to the database.

I did some research into the issue and found a similar problem here: [HERE](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano/issues/313#issuecomment-1321760360)

One of the potential solutions suggested involves replacing “localhost” with a specific “127.0.0.1” .

Taking the example server-side script from the instructions: http://132.72.155.230:3838/js/setting-up-an-sql-api.html

I think perhaps I should change the following line:

`let db = pgp("postgres://readonlyuser:whatever2@localhost:5432/gisdb");`

To:
`let db = pgp("postgres://readonlyuser:whatever2@127.0.0.1:5432/gisdb");`

Is this likely to work in my case? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick? Any suggestions welcome.

Perhaps I should update my version of node?

Apologies if the question is badly formulated I don’t post here very much.

"sudo service postgresql restart" does temporarily solve the problem.

Within ubuntu I tried “ $ sudo reboot” but the problem persists.

Comment: "Is this likely to work in my case?"  Wouldn't it have been easier to try it then to ask strangers?  I would say it is unlikely to work, since the error message in the title says it was connecting to 127.0.0.1 (as opposed to ::1) already.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting database server's log I used ```sudo nano postgresql-14-main.lo``` which reveals a pattern of errors as follows.

The database is terminated for some reason perhaps inactivity and we get;```FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command```

 Then approx. when users may be logging on we get; ```LOG:  starting PostgreSQL``` some other messages and then ```LOG:  database system is ready to accept connection```

Comment: Then: ```postgres@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-01-12 08:26:43.279 UTC [114850] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5"
2023-01-12 08:39:49.679 UTC [115841] pgsql@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2023-01-12 08:39:49.679 UTC [115841] pgsql@postgres DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.```

Comment: So I’m guessing by default the database is trying to connect to the default user “postgres” but my understanding is that having followed the instructions in section H.5 here http://132.72.155.230:3838/js/setting-up-an-sql-api.html  the reconnect should be happening as “readonly user”?  

Should I try and force this to happen somehow or should I be redefining the default user and password for “postgres”?

Comment: Databases shouldn't just shut themselves down due to inactivity.  If you are using some kind of managed provider maybe they would arrange for it to happen, but it seems like a dumb thing for them to do.  I have heard of hackers shutting down databases after using them to gain entry (presumably to prevent competing hackers from joining the party), so you might need to consider that.

Comment: Your first password error message should have come with a 2nd "DETAIL" line giving the reason for the failure.  That is what we really need to see.  Your 2nd password error is as the user "pgsql".  If you don't know why any legitimate user might be attempting to log in as that user, that also suggests hacker activity.  You should change log_line_prefix to also log IP addresses.

Comment: 2nd and third line are as follows

Comment: 2023-01-11 23:17:54.960 UTC [71229] postgres@postgres CONTEXT:  COPY //8 characters in upper and lower case 
, line 1: "/tmp/kinsing exists"

2023-01-11 23:17:54.960 UTC [71229] postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS //8digits in upper and lower case TABLE //8 characters in upper and lower case (cmd_output text);COPY //8 characters in upper and lower case FROM PROGRAM 'echo //96 characters in upper and lower case

Comment: later I also get: ```postgres@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-01-12 08:26:43.279 UTC [114850] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5"
2023-01-12 08:39:49.679 UTC [115841] pgsql@postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2023-01-12 08:39:49.679 UTC [115841] pgsql@postgres DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.```